# Convert canvas js commands to compact structure

Tags: javascript, php, regex, canvas, svg

I converted SVG image to canvas js commands using this online tool http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/

Now I show you some piece of that code:

```
...
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(1080.756,172.244);
ctx.lineTo(1077.382,175.618);
ctx.lineTo(1079.223,177.458);
ctx.lineTo(1081.677,175.004);
ctx.lineTo(1082.903,171.63);
ctx.lineTo(1080.756,172.244);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();



ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(1089.039,169.79);
ctx.lineTo(1091.492,169.79);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(1091.492,169.79,1091.492,169.79);
ctx.lineTo(1091.492,171.32399999999998);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(1091.492,171.32399999999998,1091.492,171.32399999999998);
ctx.lineTo(1089.039,171.32399999999998);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(1089.039,171.32399999999998,1089.039,171.32399999999998);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(1089.039,169.79,1089.039,169.79);
ctx.lineTo(1089.039,169.79);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
...
```

Each `beginPath-closePath` segment of code draws separate object on canvas.
As I want to do further manipulation with this objects I came to that I need to convert this list of commands to a compact structure:

```
a = [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        coords: [ 
            ['m',21,22],
            ['l',[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],
            ['b',7,8,9,10],
            ['l',[11,12],[13,14]]               
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'name2',
        coords: [ 
            ['m',21,22],
            ['l',[21,22], [23,4], [5,6]],
            ['b',[27,28,9,10], [11,12,13,14]],
            ['l',[211,212],[213,214]]               
        ]
    }           
];
```

each separate object I want to be transformed to a js object `{}`. And in this object `'coords'` property will have all the js canvas functions and coordinated represented in array way. Where first letter indicate the function (`moveTo`, `lineTo` etc.) and then - arguments of this functions. But extra thing here is that if I have multiple lines of `lineTo` functions I want to combine them to one array. So when I have code like this:

```
ctx.lineTo(1,2);
ctx.lineTo(3,4);
```

I want it to be transformed to

```
['l',[1,2], [3,4]]
```

rather then to

```
['l',[1,2]],
['l',[3,4]]
```

How am I supposed to do that?
Can't see the way to do it with php regex.
I see the solution in loops and multiple `preg_match`es and `if` clauses but really wanted to see a more simple solution.

Comment: Why use regex? You can write a parser. Seems like a nested loop.

Comment: I see the sulution in loops and multiple preg_mathches and if clauses but wanted to see something more simple.

Comment: No no, don't expand it in PHP parse it on the client side that's much simpler. Definitely don't need regex for this - you already have a JSON structure - either way iterate the JSON object - either after parsing it to a JS object on the client side or to a PHP associative array on the server.

Comment: I don't need to make it on a fly. I have on file with canvas js commands and want to get another with my structure.

Comment: so how is your actual input file(s?) look like?

Comment: Like the code I wrote above. Just after 'Now I show you some piece of that code:'

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) magic to convert `[ ['l',[1,2]],...,['l',[3,4]] ]` to `['l',[1,2],...,[3,4]]`

```
function compact_arr(data) { // helper function
  return _.union(data[0][0], _.pluck(data, [1]))
}
```

Next, scan `coords:` grouping the continous sets of 'l' (or 'b' or 'm') and calling `compact_arr()` on each group.

Comment: But I need to convert it once and save the result in file and work with that new file then. Your solution seems to convert on a fly.

Comment: Also my input file doesn't look like [ ['l',[1,2]],...,['l',[3,4]] ]. But it looks like the code I wrote in my question - just after words 'Now I show you some piece of that code:'